# Visio 2016: Can you resize a comment window?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm using Visio 2010 and it does not seems like I can resize the comment window, making it a real pain to scroll down for longer comments.

Can someone with Visio 2016 check to see if you can resize the comment window?

Answer (score 0):

Very little (or nothing) can be done with the built-in comment shape. I assume you are using these comment shapes for a formal review process.

If not then you could use a standard callout shape or even try one of Visio Guy's Sticky Note shapes.

[Visio Guy's Sticky Note shape](http://www.visguy.com/2009/04/17/visio-sticky-note-shape/)